# How do I mashup imagery from Gigapan?

Tags: arcgis-server, mashup

[image]
NASA recently published this [long imagery swath](http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Features/LDCMLongSwath/) onto [Gigapan](http://gigapan.com/gigapans/9741ab68dda60a8b05b9c1bfce147500).

Is there some way to mash up imagery from Gigapan so that it displays in a web map, using one of the [ArcGIS web mapping API's](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/web/web-apis)?

Comment: No sure the ArcGIS Web API supports it - though NASA WorldWind can http://builds.worldwind.arc.nasa.gov/worldwind-releases/daily/docs/api/index.html http://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/Feeds/GoogleEarth/long_swath_full.kml